# Are const iterators still evil in C++14

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14

Item 26 from Scott Mayers's "Effective STL" is labeled "Prefer `iterator` to `const_iterator`, `reverse_iterator` and `const reverse iterator`".

The reasoning is that some forms of `insert()` and `erase()` require exactly `iterator` and converting from the other types is tedious and error-prone. Furthermore, comparing `iterator` and `const_iterator` could be problematic, depending on the STL implementation.

The book was released at 2001. Is the advice in Item 26 still valid with the current state of gcc?

Comment: Of course `insert` and `erase` require a non-const `iterator`: They alter the data, so having `const` data would be a bad idea.

Comment: @gexicide: Wrong. If you can call `erase`, you have mutable access to the container anyways. And for that reason, C++11 changed the `erase` and `insert` functions to take `const_iterator`s (`iterator`s are always convertible to their `const_` variant).

Comment: @Xeo: Right, my mistake. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: For the OP: This was already fixed 3 years ago. :) "Effective STL" is outdated.

Comment: @Xeo, there are some shortcomings, like 'there are no standard hashed containers', 'the swap trick', 'there is no range for', but I am still at quite basic level and the rest of the material is being very helpful to me.

Comment: Scott Myers is coming out with a C++11/C++14 version of [Effective Programming](https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/01/effective-c11-update-scott-meyers) RSN.  This might offer some new insight here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The C++14 standard (N3936) guarantees that `iterator` and `const_iterator` are freely comparable (§23.2.1 [container.requirements.general]/p7):

> In the expressions
>
> ```
> i == j
> i != j
> i < j
> i <= j
> i >= j
> i > j
> i - j
> ```
>
> where `i` and `j` denote objects of a container’s `iterator` type,
>   either or both may be replaced by an object of the container’s
>   `const_iterator` type referring to the same element with no change in
>   semantics.

In addition, the container member functions take `const_iterator` parameters as of C++11 (§C.2.13 [diff.cpp03.containers] - as might be inferred from the tag, this is a change from C++03):

> **Change**: Signature changes: from `iterator` to `const_iterator` parameters
>
> **Rationale**: Overspecification. *Effects*: The signatures of the following member functions changed from taking an `iterator` to taking
>   a `const_iterator`:
>
> - `insert(iter, val)` for `vector`, `deque`, `list`, `set`, `multiset`, `map`, `multimap`
> - `insert(pos, beg, end)` for `vector`, `deque`, `list`, `forward_list`
> - `erase(iter) for`set`,`multiset`,`map`,`multimap`
> - `erase(begin, end) for`set`,`multiset`,`map`,`multimap`
> - all forms of `list::splice`
> - all forms of `list::merge`

The container requirements have been similarly changed to take const iterators. In addition, it is easy to obtain the underlying iterator from a `std::reverse_iterator` via its `.base()` member function. Thus, neither of the concerns noted in the question should be an issue in a conforming compiler.

Comment: You should explicitly mention that this is a change from C++03 -> C++11 already.

Comment: A note about reverse iterators having .base would be good too.

Answer (score 8):

The advice has been reversed, as can be seen from Item 13 of the upcoming [**Effective Modern C++**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491903996) which is titled:

> Prefer const_iterators to iterators

The reason is that C++11 and C++14 add several tweaks that make `const_iterators` a lot more practical:

C++11 adds

- member functions `cbegin()` and `cend()` (and their reverse counterparts) for all Standard Library containers
- member functions using iterators to identify positions (e.g. `insert()`, `erase()`) now take a `const_iterator` instead of an `iterator`

C++14 completes that by adding non-member `cbegin()` and `cend()`  (and their reverse counterparts)